# if summation of $i$ is $(n(n+1))/2$ what happens when you change the range?

Tags: summation

I understand:
$$\sum\limits^n_{i=1} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
what happens when we restrict the range such that:
$$\sum\limits^n_{i=n/2} i = ??$$

Originally I thought we might just have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}/2$ but I know that's not correct since starting the summation at n/2 would be the larger values of the numbers between $1..n$

Comment: One way is to use the formula with the $2$ RHS terms in $\sum\limits^n_{i=n/2} i = \sum\limits^n_{i=1} i - \sum\limits^{n/2-1}_{i=1} i$.

Comment: Let $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i$, then what you’re after is $f(n)-f(\frac{n}{2}-1)$

Comment: Thanks everyone! @JohnOmielan would that be something like: $(n(n+1))/2 - ((n/2-1)(n/2 -1 +1))/2$?

Comment: @KatieMelosto You're welcome. Yes, your expression is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what sequence you're adding up (i.e. no matter what $a_i$ is), so long as $m \lt n$ we know that 
$$\sum^{m-1}_{i = 1} a_i + \sum_{i = m}^n a_i  = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i$$

so we can bring the first term over to the right and side and get

$$\sum_{i = m}^n a_i  = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - \sum^{m-1}_{i = 1} a_i$$

Can you figure out how to apply this to your situation?

Comment: One minor point is what you're shown also works for $m = n$ as well, plus even for $m = n + 1$ if you use the standard convention that a summation with no terms, e.g., $\sum_{i=n+1}^{n}a_i$, is $0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Yeah, I even hesitated before adding the condition $m \lt n$, as I thought there might be a convention that a sum from higher to lower index was equal to the negative of the lower to higher version (similar to integrals), but I guessed that the least complicated answer best fit the original question. But I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even of the form $2p$, the sum is
$$(p+0)+(p+1)+(p+2)+...+(p+n-p)=$$

$$p(n-p+1)+1+2+3+...(n-p)=$$

$$p(n-p+1)+\frac{(n-p)(n-p+1)}{2}=$$

$$\frac{(n-p+1)(n+p)}{2}$$

If $n$ is odd of the form $2p-1$, we get the same sum.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotic solution: the difference, let's call it $S_d = S_1 - S_2$ can be obtained by taking the largest term in each sum, i.e. $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{n(n+2)}{8}:$
$$
S_d = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{n(n+2)}{8} = \frac{3 n^2}{8} + \frac{n}{4} = O(n^2)
$$
so asymptotically the difference is of the same order as both sums.